# Use Anaconda package manager in Winpython

Tags: python, anaconda, package

I'm using Winpython to do a project but i'm struggling to install a package with pip. This package is easily installed using "conda install" in my Anaconda. I would like to know if there is some way to use the conda package manager in Winpython (i.e install package using conda install in Winpython)

Answer (score 0):

No. Depending of what you miss:

- download big binary packages from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) in a local directory "d:\toto"
- "pip install --pre  --no-index --trusted-host=None  --find-links=d:\toto your_package"

or

- "pip install d:\toto\your_package_wheel_exact_name"